# $PATH in the .bashrc

Tags: gcc, bashrc, arm

How I can do [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md):

> #### INSTALL TOOLCHAIN
>
> ... add  `/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin` to your $PATH in the `.bashrc` in your home directory.

I managed to find the `.bashrc` file and open it.

`gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin` is a file on my PC

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on vmware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file with any editor of your choice, then add the following that line in this manner:

```
export PATH="/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin:$PATH"
```

Then either:

1. Source the file with: `source ~/.bashrc`, OR
2. Restart the system but step one is better

Check if it's there with this command:

```
echo $PATH | grep -i /tools/arm-bcm2708/
```

If it's there you will see it in the output, if not your syntax may be off.

Answer (score 1):

One way for adding the path to the file is:

You should edit `~/.bashrc` file, e.g. using:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

And add the following line to the end of the file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin
```

The above line will add the specific path to the end of the lists of paths in PATH variable